# Why is voting to close a question not possible after retracting?

Tags: discussion, votes

I voted to close a question because the question was "Unclear what you are asking". The question has been edited and it was not unclear anymore, but it was now very clearly off-topic.

So I retracted the vote to change it to "Off topic", but I am not able to vote again.

> You voted to close this question 55 mins ago
>   You retracted your vote 31 mins ago

Why is it not possible to vote to close a question after retracting a previous vote?

I noticed that behaviour before, but the current case is about this question: [PostgreSQL query to C#](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266105/postgresql-query-to-c/266113)

Comment: Stack Exchange (not just GIS SE) has a mechanism for this please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23701/why-cant-i-change-my-vote-if-the-post-has-been-edited-during-the-initial-5mn-gr/38759#38759

Comment: Thanks. But that link is not about close votes

Comment: try https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/167514#167514

Comment: The question is a bit different but some ideas below and comments answer my question. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This comment from @animuson from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-retract-a-close-vote-before-it-closes/167514#167514) answers my question quite well:

> allowing them to vote again would allow them to quickly retract their vote then vote to close again to bump it back into the Close Votes queue after receiving enough Leave Open votes to kick it out. It's just as prone to abuse. Once you've cast your vote, you've cast your vote. That shouldn't be undoable.